# Is there a way to disable custom patterns with a comment in Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, structural-search

In Resharper normal hints are able to be disabled by a comment via the

```
Disable once with comment
```

option on the context menu when you press `<ctrl-enter>`

With custom structural search patterns

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/19/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/

I can't find a way to do this. There is no option on the context menu to disable the hint.

Is it possible to disable custom patterns with comments?

Comment: There is the following ticket in YouTrack http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-182449. So, I don't think it is possible now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wanted to tell you, issue has been resolved.

You can add a suppression key now (when editing the pattern), which is used in the comment then.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/06/20/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-build-4/